# Permissão de acesso numa aplicação delphi

Tags: delphi-xe3, windows-7

Bom dia!

Estou utilizando o Inno Setup para gerar um instalador de minha aplicação Delphi.

Na aplicação, preciso ler variaveis de registro do Windows em HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:

if Registry.OpenKey('\Software\Empresa\'+'Sistema\', True) then
  showmessage('Abriu Chave de Registro para Leitura!');

Mas só consigo realizar essa operação se executo o sistema como "Administrador".
Minha dúvida é: Como faço para criar uma instalação no Inno Setup que já dá permissão ao executável para realizar
leitura e escrita no registro?

Grata pela atenção

Comment: Essa é uma prerrogativa do sistema operacional e não do programa.

Comment: Oi Reginaldo, obrigada por responder.

Então, eu fiz uma aplicação mínima apenas com um botão
na tela que ao clicar tenta acessar o registro do windows.
Quando compilo o codigo em delphi 7, a máquina do cliente
acessa a chave de registro e quando compilo no delphi xe3,
a máquina não acessa a chave de registro.
Deve ser alguma opção na compilação entre um delphi e outro.
Mas não sei qual.

Comment: Em que pasta estão instalados esses Delphis, o 7 e o XE3?

Comment: Os delphis estão em c:\arquivos de programa

Comment: Não sei se poderia ser esse o problema, mas sei que o Delphi XE quando instalado na pasta Arquivos de Programas é problemático. Os programas no cliente, também estão rodando na pasta Arquivos de Programas?

Comment: sim....mas acabei de ver uma dica de como executar um exe com privilégios...precisei criar um arquivo manifest de permissões e em seguida compilar com modificação na opção "Custom Manifest" do Project/Options/Application/ "Runtime Themes". Agora ao executar o exe pergunta se quer executar como administrador. Mas preciso estudar o arquivo manifest na tag TrustInfo para executar como administrador sem perguntar.

Comment: consegui. modifiquei a tag <trustInfo> <applicationRequestMinimum>PermissionSet ID="FullTrust" Unrestricted="true" /> e agora abre direto sem perguntar e consegue executar como administrador e acessar a chave de registro.

Comment: Poste uma resposta a sua propria pergunta. Outras pessoas podem se beneficiar disso.